# cypher query in java: get and iterate resultset nodes

Tags: java, api, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

```
public class BooksManager {
    
    //private final Driver driver;
    private final ConnectionConfig config;
    private Connection con;
    public BooksManager(ConnectionConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.con = null;
        try {
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:"+ config.getFullUrl(), "neo4j", config.getPassword());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

public void viewBook(){
    booksQuery = "USE eindb MATCH (b:Book) RETURN b LIMIT 25";

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(booksQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    ResultSet rs = null;
        
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            
            Object bookJustObject = rs.getObject("b");
            System.out.println("b: "+bookJustObject);
            //TODO get all fields from object, how? 
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I execute successfull query which return some books.
Query run with jdbc connection for neo4j database.
I don't understand how to list all fields from object "b" which represents a book in graph database.

Comment: It can work if I cast object to Map for retrieve fields key and value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. Some pointers:

to return a specific set of properties

```
RETURN b.title AS title, b.foo AS foo
```

to return properties as a map:

```
RETURN properties(b) AS map
```

to return properties and add the node id.

```
RETURN apoc.map.setKey(properties(b),'id',id(b)) AS mapWithId
```

to return a list of all properties/keys

```
MATCH (b:Book) 
UNWIND keys(b) AS key
RETURN DISTINCT key
```